# How to import json into ES modules in nodejs v14+?

Tags: node.js

With commonjs, I can import a json file as an object like this:

```js
const json = require("path/to/my-json-file.json");
```

How should I do it in ES modules in node 14+?

Comment: `import myJson from 'path/to/my-json-file.json'`

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent in ES modules would be:

```js
import fs from "fs";
const json = JSON.parse(
  fs.readFileSync(new URL("path/to/my-json-file.json", import.meta.url), {
    encoding: "utf-8",
  })
);
```

Note the path is the relative path to the file (because `import.meta.url` works similarly as the old `__filename`).